# list.notify() throws an exception

Tags: java, android

i have to remove a object from my List within my BaseCardAdapter. This BaseCardAdapter is used for my SwipeCardView. I try to remove an object after pressing a button. After that i need to notify the adapter that one object is removed. Unfortunately i receive this error:

> java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()

Here is my Code:

```
public class FeedAdapter extends BaseCardAdapter {

private ArrayList<EventObject> events;
private Activity activity;
private TextView property1, property2, property3, usernameage;
private ImageView userthumb;

public FeedAdapter(ArrayList<EventObject> events, Activity activity) {
    this.events = events;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return events.size();
}

@Override
public int getCardLayoutId() {
    return R.layout.model_idea_feed;
}

@Override
public void onBindData(final int position, View cardview) {
    if (events.size() == 0 || events == null){
        return;
    }
    ImageView thumb = cardview.findViewById(R.id.feed_thumb_model);
    userthumb = cardview.findViewById(R.id.feed_profile_thumb);

    final TextView eventname = cardview.findViewById(R.id.feed_name_model);
    usernameage  = cardview.findViewById(R.id.feed_username_model);
    TextView date = cardview.findViewById(R.id.feed_date_model);
    TextView additional = cardview.findViewById(R.id.feed_additional_model);
    TextView address = cardview.findViewById(R.id.feed_adress_model);
    property1 = cardview.findViewById(R.id.feed_property1_model);
    property2 = cardview.findViewById(R.id.feed_property2_model);
    property3 = cardview.findViewById(R.id.feed_property3_model);

    ImageButton save = cardview.findViewById(R.id.feed_savebtn_model);
    ImageButton accept = cardview.findViewById(R.id.feed_accept_model);

    switch(Integer.parseInt(events.get(position).getPosition())) {
        case 0:
          thumb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.berlin0);
            break;
        case 1:
           thumb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.berlin1);

            break;
        case 2:
            thumb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.berlin2);

            break;
        default:
            thumb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.berlin2);
            break;
    }

    eventname.setText(events.get(position).getName());
    date.setText(events.get(position).getDate());
    additional.setText(events.get(position).getInfos());
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(activity, Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(events.get(position).getLat()),Double.parseDouble(events.get(position).getLng()), 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
        String adderess = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
        address.setText(adderess);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            events.remove(events.get(position));
      //Here Appears the error:

      events.notify();

        }
    });



}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notify()` is something completely unrelated to lists and Adapters.

What you want is `notifyDataSetChanged()`, called on the Adapter itself, not the data list.

Replace:

```
events.notify();
```

With:

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Or:

```
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Comment: cannot select notifyDataSetChanged or notifyItemRemoved, i can only select notify or notifyall

Comment: Like I said, you don't call it on the list. Put _exactly_ what I wrote.

Comment: i solved it by using an ArrayAdapter instead of BaseCardAdapter . @TheWanderer in BaseCardAdapter you cannot use notifiyDataSetChanged or notifyItemRemoved because its not available

Comment: What is BaseCardAdapter? It's not part of the Android API.